# FORTRAN allocatable arrays. What is the mathematical representation of this segment of code?

Tags: math, fortran, fortran90

What is happening in this segment of code?

```
DOUBLE PRECISION, INTENT(IN) :: x(3,3), y(3,3)
DOUBLE PRECISION :: e(3,3) 

do i=1,3
j=mod(i,3)+1

e(:,i)=x(:,j)-x(:,i)

done
```

Comment: Are you sure you copied it right? As it is, it fills in the array `e` with values of zero or `nan` (wherever `x` contains values of `inf` or `nan`). `j` is always equal to `i` in that loop, so you are really just subtracting `x` from itself.

Comment: j sequences through `2,3,1` as i goes `1,2,3`.

Comment: @agentp Yes. Thanks for correcting me there. I'm not sure why I misread that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put simply, this takes each column and subtracts it (element by element) from the one following it with indices wrapping around the array.

i.e. the first column of `e` contains the second column of `x` minus the first column of `x`, the second column of `e` contains the third column of `x` minus the second, and the third column of `e` contains the first column of `x` minus the third.